# How can I replace a single component of a value in a Datatable?

Tags: r, shiny, shinyapps

I am trying to replace the variables '030,066,008,030,066,008' with 100,066,008,100,066,008' in a R shiny app. At the moment, it does not. When I replace all of the values, it works.

Important: I only want to replace a portion of the values, not the complete set.

Could someone please assist me in resolving this problem?

**CSV DATA**

```
ID  Type  Category    values
21  A1     B1          030,066,008,030,066,008
22  C1     D1          020,030,075,080,095,100
23  E1     F1          030,085,095,060,201,030
```

**App.R**

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(dplyr)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fileInput("file1", "Choose CSV File", accept = ".csv"),
      checkboxInput("header", "Header", TRUE),
      selectInput("col", "Column to search:", NULL),
      textInput("old", "Replace:"),
      textInput("new", "By:"),
      actionButton("replace", "Replace!"),
    ),
    mainPanel(
      DTOutput("table1")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  my_data <- reactiveVal(NULL)
  
  observeEvent(input$file1, {
    file <- input$file1
    ext <- tools::file_ext(file$datapath)
    req(file)
    validate(need(ext == "csv", "Please upload a csv file"))
    my_data(read.csv(file$datapath, header = input$header))
    updateSelectInput(session, "col", choices = names(my_data()))
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$replace, {
    req(input$col)
    dat <- req(my_data())
    traf <- if (is.numeric(dat[[input$col]])) as.numeric else identity
    my_data(dat %>%
              mutate(!!rlang::sym(input$col) := 
                       replace(!!rlang::sym(input$col),
                               as.character(!!rlang::sym(input$col)) == input$old,
                               input$new) %>% 
                       traf()))
  })
  
  output$table1 <- renderDT(
    req(my_data())
  )
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: What are you putting into your "by" and "replace" boxes? It worked fine for me when I put 030,066,008,030,066,008 into the "by" box and 100,066,008,100,066,008 into the "replace" box (the new values in the table for the first row then changed to be 100,066,008,100,066,008 )

Comment: @NovaEthos, For instance, I'd like to write 030 in the replace box and 100 in the by box. When I tried it, it didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible solution using `stringr`. I just changed the `replace` function by `str_replace_all` from `stringr` package.

EDIT : you can use a regex as pattern to detect, in order to specify you want to detect the exact number, and not if it is parts of another number.

Example : `str_replace_all("0300", "030", "100")` will return 1000 whereas
`str_replace_all("0300", my_regex("030"), "100")` will return 0300, with `my_regex` a regex to specify you want the exact pattern (i must admit i do not have the regex to use in my mind right now ...)

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fileInput("file1", "Choose CSV File", accept = ".csv"),
      checkboxInput("header", "Header", TRUE),
      selectInput("col", "Column to search:", NULL),
      textInput("old", "Replace:"),
      textInput("new", "By:"),
      actionButton("replace", "Replace!"),
    ),
    mainPanel(
      DTOutput("table1")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  my_data <- reactiveVal(NULL)
  
  observeEvent(input$file1, {
    file <- input$file1
    ext <- tools::file_ext(file$datapath)
    req(file)
    # validate(need(ext == "csv", "Please upload a csv file"))
    my_data(read.csv2(file$datapath, header = input$header))
    updateSelectInput(session, "col", choices = names(my_data()))
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$replace, {
    req(input$col)
    dat <- req(my_data())
    traf <- if (is.numeric(dat[[input$col]])) as.numeric else identity

    my_data(dat %>%
              mutate(!!rlang::sym(input$col) := 
                       stringr::str_replace_all(!!rlang::sym(input$col),
                               input$old,
                               input$new) %>% 
                       traf()))
  })
  
  output$table1 <- renderDT(
    req(my_data())
  )
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: @KevinTracey Pabort is right about the fact that if you have 0300 it will replace it by 1000 and maybe you don't want it. But you can use a regex in str_replace_all(string, pattern, replacement) for the pattern to look for. And with a regex you can specify you want the exact "030" and not detect "0300" or "1030" for example.

Answer (score 2):

I assumed you want to filter the dataset by column and by row, and assumed the row value it's always going to be ID (if not, you can put another selectInput for that)

Note: using `stringr::str_replace_all` is actually more clever, but since I used my entire afternoon, I wanted to post my solution anyways...

Note2: wouldnt `stringr::str_replace_all` replace the value `03000` with `10000`? Nice, then my solution is better!

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(dplyr)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fileInput("file1", "Choose CSV File", accept = ".csv"),
      checkboxInput("header", "Header", TRUE),
      textInput("row", "Select row by ID:"),
      selectInput("col", "Column to search:", NULL),
      textInput("old", "Replace:", value="030"),
      textInput("new", "By:", value ="100"),
      actionButton("replace", "Replace!"),
    ),
    mainPanel(
      DTOutput("table1")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  ## two reactVal, one for the dataset and another for the vector with new values
  my_data <- reactiveVal(NULL)
  vector1 <- reactiveVal(NULL)
  
  observeEvent(input$file1, {
    file <- input$file1
    ext <- tools::file_ext(file$datapath)
    req(file)
    validate(need(ext == "csv", "Please upload a csv file"))
    my_data(read.csv(file$datapath, header = input$header))
    updateSelectInput(session, "col", choices = names(my_data()))
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$replace, {
    req(input$col, input$row, input$new, input$old)
    my_data <- my_data()
    old <- input$old
    new <- input$new
    col1 <- input$col
    row1 <- input$row
    ## create a new vector by:
    vector1(
      my_data %>%
        filter(ID == row1) %>%            ## 1. filtering by row
        select(all_of(col1)) %>%          ## 2. selecting column
        stringr::str_split(",") %>%       ## 3. creating a list of values separated by ','
        unlist() %>%                      ## 4. unlisting the values into a vector of values
        replace(., . == old, new)  %>%    ## 5. changing old values for new values
        paste0(collapse = ",")            ## 6. colapsing all values of vector with ','
    )
    ## replace that vector in the dataframe
    my_data <-  my_data %>% 
      mutate(values = ifelse(ID == row1, vector1(), values))
    
    my_data(my_data)
    
  })
  
  output$table1 <- renderDT(
    req(my_data())
  )
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: That is relevant. I edited my own question to specify a regex can be used.